# Snippet file corrupt

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

When trying to override a base class method, I'm now getting an error as the Code Snippet Manager doesn't know how to process it.

[image]

I've looked online and [this msdn link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/1d2ebf54-c0fd-4502-a257-ed96243119ea/) which suggested checking if the `Method Override Stub` xml file was corrupted.

I've determined that the file: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Refactoring\MethodOverrideStub.snippet` is indeed corrupt.

**Where do I get a new one?**

I might have to reinstall VS, but if there is another way - ie, can someone post their copy of the xml file on [github:gist](https://gist.github.com/) or here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run setup and choose "Repair" option.

I recommend this, because you may have more corrupted files.

Comment: Actually tried to run my install disc and setup.exe failed to load :/ thanks for the tip and the file - it works great.